# Imacro como reiniciar ou continuar o script

Tags: javascript, script, firefox, macro, automatização

Tenho usado o imacro nesses sites de bicoins, e funciona perfeitamente o processo. porem não é 100%. Eu preciso de um código para colocar no final do processo do script que faça ele procurar a palavra no site, caso a encontre começar o processo de novo, caso não, esperar 3600 segundos.

Quando erra aparece escrito: "Incorrect captcha entered" que seria pelo imacro:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=ID:free_play_error
```

E quando acerta: "You win"

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:free_play_result
```

Segue o final do script:

```
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:adcopy_response CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
TAG POS=19 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:×
wait seconds=3600
```

Basicamente aqui ele fecha a Tab, cola o captcha no local certo e dá play, porém as vezes o captcha vem errado. Dai eu precisaria um uma função para que ele consiga distinguir se o processo deu certo ou não. Caso tenha dado certo, esperar os 3600 segundos, caso não, iniciar o script do início.

Answer (score 0):

Como descrito no site do iMacros, ele não permite o uso de condicionais, pela maneira que foi desenvolvido.

> The iMacros language itself is designed as a descriptive language (similar to HTML) and does not contain conditional statements.
>   [iMacros FAQ](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_Are_there_conditional_statements_like_if..._then...else_in_the_iMacros_macro_language.3F)

A maneira mais fácil de contornar este problema é criar um programa em outra linguagem e chamar macros menores e específicos para cada momento da sua aplicação.

Segue o exemplo usado por eles:

```
ReturnCode = iim1.iimPlay ("YourMacro1")
 if ReturnCode = 1 then
  'Do something
  MsgBox "OK!"
 else
   'Do something else
   ReturnCode = iim1.iimPlay ("YourMacro2")
 end if
```

Algumas das linguagens que você pode utilizar são:
 `VBS`, `VB`, `VBA`, `VB.NET`, `Perl`, `Java`, `Foxpro`, `C`, `C++`, `C#`, `ASP`, `ASP.NET`, `PHP` entre outras.

Quando tiver o programa chamando os macros e realizando a atividade corretamente, apenas inclua um laço de repetição como `while`, `FOR` e `LOOP`.